# Automating the rumour identification process

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, prediction, naivebayes

Currenlty what we do, check the user discussion based on some keywords on social media. As per the keywords detection we identify that this can be rumour.

Approach to automate the process:

1. Keyword based : verifying the conversation for 1-2 gram based keywords. If keyword present, marking it as suspected conversation
2. Classifier based approach : Training the classifier with some prelabeled suspected conversations. Which ever being classified with >50% probability, marked as suspected.

For 2nd approach I am thinking of naive bayes classifier, and identifying the result with precision, recall, F measure value using scikit learn.

Is there any better approach to this? Or some model which can be combination of both approach?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason that the two approaches would be mutually exclusive. If you are going to be identifying keywords anyway, then you could easily extract a feature for machine-learning. And if you are doing machine-learning, you might as well include features that capture what you know about the keywords you have identified.

Is there a reason that you have chosen a Naive Bayes model? You may want to try a number of models to compare their performance. Your statement about 'identifying the result with precision, recall, F-measure' makes it seem like you don't understand how you make predictions with a machine-learning model. Those three metrics are the result of comparing a model's predictions with 'gold-standard' labels on a number of texts. I would recommend reading through an introduction to machine-learning. If you have already decided that you want to use `scikit-learn`, then perhaps you could work through their tutorial [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html). Another `python` library worth looking into is `nltk`, which has a free companion book [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

If `python` is not your preferred language, then there are lots of other options, too. For example, `weka` is a well-known tool written in java. It has a very user-friendly graphical interface for the basic functions, but it is not difficult to use from the command line as well.

Good luck!

Comment: @bepop: thanks for your answer. ACtually I am comfortable with scikit learn as well nltk. reason behind naive bayes is, I read it functions well with text data. I guess I can compare with different models like svm, naive bayes, max entropy too. As per my understanding after your answer, I can use precision, recall, F measure to compare results among different models right?

Comment: I have two alternative, nltk or scikit learn. Can you please give your approach for this scenario

Comment: @cyclic Yes, if you have a gold standard corpus, then you can train and test models on that corpus (typically using 10-fold cross-validation), and the results of those tests (including precision, recall, etc.) can be used to compare models, assuming that their training data and testing data are identical. `nltk` and `scikit-learn` are both excellent libraries. I would recommend looking at which models are available in each. Just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @cyclic By the way, I just learned a week ago about `orange`, yet another possibility for `python`. The newest version for `python3` is primarily built on `scikit-learn`.